# ScatterView runtime exception on x64

Tags: .net, wpf, 64-bit, pixelsense, scatterview

I have the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187718/surface-runtime-exception-on-windows-8).

We have developed several applications using the old [Microsoft Surface 2.0 SDK.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26716)  The applications are built as `AnyCPU` and those work perfectly fine running both in 32 bit and 64 bit mode. In one of these application I use a `ScatterView`.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <s:ScatterView x:Name="timeline">
            <Rectangle></Rectangle>
        </s:ScatterView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

However if I try to add a new `ScatterView` in a new blank `Window` I get this error:

```cs
{"The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Surface.Core.InteractiveSurface' threw an exception."}

System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233036
Message=The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Input.InteractiveSurface'  threw an exception.
Source=Microsoft.Surface.Presentation
TypeName=Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Input.InteractiveSurface
```

If I force the application to run in `32 bit` it runs perfectly. However the application is pretty memory intensive so I would like to run it in `64 bit` as well.

**My question is**: How come the ScatterView in my current application runs perfectly in 64 bit, but adding an additional ScatterView to this application or creating a brend new application crashes immediately.  Unfortunately the answer given in the previous questions has a dead link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course after 48 hours of searching I found a solution to my own question.

When you add an item in the `ScatterView`, a call is made to the function `GetItemOrientation` in `Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Controls.ScatterCanvas`. This function determines the rotation of the `ScatterViewItem`. When running your application in `64bit` this method fails and throws an exception, probably caused by a call to a native method to determine the orientation of the SUR40 on which it is supposed to run.

**Solution:**
You can disable the function call to `GetItemOrientation` by setting the  `Orientation` property on the `ScatterViewItem` yourself or by setting `ScatterViewItem.CanRotate = false`.